# how to populate jquery datatables with json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

I am using jquery datatable in my application, plugin link https://datatables.net/

I want to populate my datatable with JSON, but I am failed.here is my code.

HTML:

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>id</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Code</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>isActive</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>id</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Code</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>isActive</th>
                            </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                            <tbody>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("hi ready");
    $('#example').DataTable({

        retrieve: true,
        ajax: {

            url: '/ProductLicensingApplication/feature/list',
            dataSrc: ''
        },

        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "code" },
            { "data": "description" },
            { "data": "isActive" }
        ]
    });
} );
```

my json 
[image: json data]

but I am not able to populate data into the table as the table shows no data available in the table..you can see in the image

[image]
please tell me what is the problem in my code...

Comment: Do you get any error messages in your console log? In the example that you can find [here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) they are using the same approach as you, but they are not defining the columns in javascript. Only in html. Also your `<tbody>` should be removed or at least before the `<tfoot>`. Since the examples do not contain a `<tbody>` i guess you can  remove it anyway.

Comment: no i am not getting any error in console, i have seen that example but its ajax data is different from my JSON data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax). The `ajax.dataSrc` option is used to tell DataTables where the data array is in the JSON structure. An empty string is a special case which tells DataTables to expect an array.

In your case JSON is an object and you should set `dataSrc : 'features'`

Answer (score 1):

Ahmad,

Either set `dataSrc : 'features'` or if possible rename the attribute name 'features' to 'data' in the response data.